# I want to achieve, Hierarchical Structure using self calling component, does it need to be declared in the AppModule?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am actually having a bit of a trouble in achieving Hierarchical Structure using selector. The app is currently in lazy loading structure. The component I created is a template for a parent. I successfully display the data in first go (Hierarchy 1, Hierarchy 2) because these are head. But in the second, (Hierarchy 1.1, Hierarchy 1.2), crashes the app and there, I called the selector itself. Do I need to make this as a page or would it be okay as a component to call the selector?

EXPECTED RESULTS:

- Hierarchy 1

  - Hierarchy 1.1
  - Hierarchy 1.2

    - Hierarchy 1.2.1
- Hierarchy 2

  - Hierarchy 2.1
- Hierarchy 3

[CODE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC5O9.png)

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview

Comment: If there is no stopping condition to stop the recursive calling of `unit` component, then your code will run infinitely. You can at least add some condition like `if no further child exists` then stop.

Comment: @AmitChigadani It works for me! Thanks!